# Is it secure to rewrite proxy a https url to http?

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, proxy, url-rewriting

Say I have an url that is served over HTTPS, but in my .htaccess I rewrite proxy it to another domain that is on the same server like so:

```
RewriteRule /https-url/(.*) http://www.somesite.com/$1 [P,L]
```

Is this a secure situation? I would assume it is, because the browser is communicating with an SSL secured url and the rewriting is done on the server where nobody can interfere.

---

**EDIT:** I just went on and tried it. It works just fine, you can just redirect people to https if they approach the http url directly. This has also saved me some money since I only had to buy an SSL certificate for one domain.

Comment: Good question. The other case (http->https) is a standard usage to enforce https. Now this case (https->http) is trickier. It could be as you say (the connection is kept, so it stays SSL OR it acts as protocol downgrade, which needs a new unencrypted connection . So far I get no good clue from the mod_rewrite documentation. Have you tried it out yet?

Comment: After some more reading I believe that the SSL connection stays (first option), the second case (downgrade) would need an explicit R=301 option in the rewrite rule.

Comment: Ok so I'm good according to you?

Comment: No, this is just speculation. I found no clear example, no explicit documentation. Why not do a test setup and monitor what is going on?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to test this. I mean I can set it up, but how will I know wether the data sent over SSL is secure?

Comment: Use some network debuging tool, wireshark (http://www.wireshark.org/) or fiddler2. Some tool that allows you to see the requests and responses over the network. For a served file which has human readable format it should be obvious if the data is encrypted or not.

Comment: I think the result I get examining the requests will not be different whether the url i'm rewriting to is http or https. Because that is handled server side. The question is if rewriting to http comes with security risks as opposed to also put the url rewritten to behind ssl. And I don't have an idea how to test that.

Comment: What problem do you expect different from the communication not being encrypted?

Comment: Other than it doesn't feel right: none. I already said I think it's safe... but I've never done this before so maybe there could be something I'm overlooking and I can't find anything about it in other questions or the internet. That's why I came here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **www.somesite.com** is hosted on the same server that the rule is being applied on, then it's network traffic is never leaving the server. That means a 3rd party not on the server won't be able to "eavesdrop" the contents of the request and response (or masquerade as a trusted party) so it doesn't matter if it's unencrypted. The assumption here is that if someone can get access to this traffic, they've already compromised the server so the reverse proxy may be the least of your worries.

Comment: So what you are saying is this will be safe (data I send will be encrypted and not decryptable) unless the rewrite would be to another server?

Comment: I think he points out that the communications from server to redirected server is safe. The more interesting question is if the communications from the browser to the initial server is still safe.